# Abort (HTTP 500) request when exception in request's handleEnd()

Tags: vert.x

I'm using vert.x-web to implement a small service. One of my handlers for the end of the request (set via `context.request().endHandler()`) throws this `NullPointerException`:

```
2018-09-02 20:54:35,125 - ERROR [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] (ContextImpl.java:345) - lambda$wrapTask$2() 
 Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at (My handler class)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.handleEnd(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:417)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleEnd(Http1xServerConnection.java:482)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleContent(Http1xServerConnection.java:477)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.processMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:458)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:144)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:712)
at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl$ServerHandlerWithWebSockets.handleMessage(HttpServerImpl.java:619)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.lambda$channelRead$1(VertxHandler.java:146)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:337)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:195)
at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:144)
```

Why doesn't this exception call my requests's exception handler? Why is it unhandled? I have the request's exception handler set to `context.fail()` (via `context.request().exceptionHandler()`). But it does not seem to have any effect.

Is there another exception handler I'm unaware of?

Edit: here is the minimal reproducing code:

```java
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(context -> {
   context.request()
      .exceptionHandler(context::fail)
      .endHandler(nothing -> { throw new NullPointerException("null"); })
      .handler(buffer -> {});
}); 
vertx.createHttpServer()
   .requestHandler(router::accept)
   .listen(8080);
```

Expected behavior: `context.fail(e)` gets called and the connection closes with HTTP ERROR 500.

Got behavior: context is not failed, connection "hangs".

Comment: Please share a bit of your code, since it's impossible to guess by stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The `exceptionHandler` applies to the `HttpServerRequest` object. The method is inherited from the `ReadStream` interface. This callback is invoked whenever a problem occurs in the Vert.x/Netty code handling HTTP requests, not user code.

If you want to execute some code before the actual request processing, I would suggest to register a route and invoke `RoutingContext#next` in the handler:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

router.route("/somepath").handler(routingContext -> {
  // Handler invoked first
  // Execute pre-processing logic
  // And then...
  context.next();
});

router.route("/somepath").handler(routingContext -> {
  // Handler invoked second
  // Execute processing logic
});
```

Then any failure in pre-processing logic will be caught and managed normally by the router.

Comment: Your code does not seem to solve the problem. It's not the routing, that fails, but the handler for the `HttpServerRequest`. And that exception does not seem to call any of my callbacks, in fact, it makes the connection "hang".

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be pointed out here:

- The hang is caused by the response is not explicitly ended (see [HttpServerResponse#end()](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerResponse.html#end--).
- To handle exception happened during request handling, add failure handler at route level (see [Route#failureHandler()](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Route.html#failureHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-)). Handling exception on request will only caught exception when reading the stream.

For example:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().failureHandler(handler -> handler.response().end());
router.route().handler(routingContext -> routingContext.request().endHandler(handler -> {
  throw new NullPointerException("exception here!");
}));
vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8085);
```